# problem with ajax update on subsequent uses

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, playframework

I've got a form that opens in a jquery-ui dialog, submits via ajax, reads updated data in json format and updates the page.  Everything works fine the first time.  On subsequent runs, the data is updated in the database correctly but the updates on the page are applied to the same cell as the first run.

Using "View Generated Source" in the Web Developer toolbar I can see that the old form is still in the DOM.  So I suspect that this `$("form#hostEdit").find("input#id").val()` is either always finding the first form, or is only being evaluated once.  I'm pretty new to jQuery though so I'm not sure what to do about it.  Should that form still be in the DOM?  Should i be using a different selector?  Something else completely?

```
$("table.hostgrid a.new").click(function() {
  var id = this.id.substring(3);
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
  .load('/hosts/new?byte1=${network.byte1}&byte2=${network.byte2}&byte3=${network.byte3}&byte4=' + id);
  var getHostAction = #{jsAction @NetworkHosts.view(':id') /}

  $dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'New host at ${network.byte1}.${network.byte2}.${network.byte3}.' + id,
    width: 500,
    buttons: {
      "Create": function() {
        $.ajax({
          async: true,
          type: 'post',
          url: '/hosts/create',
          data: $("form#hostNew").serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
            $dialog.html(response);
            if ($("div.flashSuccess") != null) {
              $dialog.dialog('destroy');
              $.ajax({
                url: getHostAction({'id': $("form#hostEdit").find("input#id").val()}),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                  updateHost(data);
                },
                error: function(data, msg, exception) {
                  alert("Error during request: " + msg);
                },
              });                  
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  $dialog.dialog('open');

  return false;
});
```

function that applies the updates:

```
function updateHost(host) {
  var cell = $("td#dot"+host.byte4);
  cell.fadeOut("fast", function() {
    cell.find("span.hostname").text(host.hostname).attr("title", host.description);
    cell.removeClass().addClass(host.agegroup);
    if (host.type) 
      cell.addClass(host.type.toLowerCase());
    if (host.is_dhcp)
      cell.addClass("dhcp");
    if (host.is_service)
      cell.addClass("service");

    cell.fadeIn("fast");
  });
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can reformat your code to use only two spaces for the indent size in order to make it more readable?

Comment: @Chris - it was a little excessive for some reason.  Updated

Comment: where r u updating $("form#hostEdit").find("input#id") value?

Comment: @ifaour - the form is part of the response.  The `$dialog.html(response);` line replaces the dialog's contents with the returned form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct, `$("form#hostEdit")` is indeed finding the first form you loaded, this because of how the dialog widget behaves.

When you do this: `$dialog.html(response);`, you're loading that HTML response into the DOM, where the dialog element (the `<div>` you created) is, and when you do this: `$dialog.dialog('destroy');` you're destroying **the dialog widget**, not the *content* in it...it's still in the DOM just not wrapped in those dialog container elements anymore.

For what you want, you need to explicitly [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) that content you loaded as well, like this:

```
$dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
```

*Then* you'll get the expected behavior, since there's not an element with that duplicate ID still in the DOM.

Comment: i guess he should save the $("form#hostEdit").find("input#id").val() before removing the dialog completely...right?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what you updateHost() function does, it is going to be really hard to determine what is going wrong. Is there anyway to link to a functional version of this on the web?

In general, when it comes to forms, you want to use an ID to ensure you are always dealing with the right one, especially if you have more then one on the page. Second, if you are trying to replace the content of that form, then no, you probably should not have two of them on the page. You will need to remove the first one and replace it with whatever the data is that is being returned from your second AJAX call.

I definitely have to question why you need two AJAX calls to accomplish whatever it is you are doing. Should the backend not be able to carry out whatever tasks you are doing in the frontend and simply return the final information?

Also, if you are replacing your form, you will need to rebind the click event to the new DOM object using something like live or livequery. Events are only bound when the page first loads.

Hopefully one of those suggestions helps.

Comment: I posted the source for updateHost, but it's just applying the returned json data so I don't think the problem is there.  Since `$dialog.dialog('destroy')` isn't removing the dialog's contents from the DOM, is there something else I should be doing so that I don't end up with multiple copies with the same ID?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can create ONE dialog instance and just update its content or with your approach after destroying your dialog:

```
var id = $("form#hostEdit").find("input#id").val();
$dialog.remove();
```

And then use the *id* variable in the next ajax request.